# MYSQL relational database

Tags: mysql, relational-database

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13386

im following the article above and i am getting error at the first quoted code

```
#1049 - Unknown database 'library'
CREATE TABLE  `library`.`books` (
 `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `name` VARCHAR( 150 ) NOT NULL ,
 `author_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
INDEX (  `author_id` )
) ENGINE = INNODB
```

the other one generates with no problem but this one, why?

Comment: You don't expect us to read the full article do you? Please state the actual problem in short in the question.

Comment: @Johan I've answered without reading the article, because the query and the error messages shown here is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table name is prepended with the database name "library". Probably your DB is named differently. If you're executing within the DB that you're using just remove the "`library`." prefix.

```
 CREATE TABLE `books` (
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "library" part from the `CREATE TABLE` statement. The other block in that article works because it doesn't reference "library".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `library.` - just use what ever database you're using, ie

```
CREATE TABLE books (...
```

And while you're at it, remove all those unnecessary backticks - they are only required when using *reserved words* (which you should avoid like the plague anyway)

Answer (score 0):

The table `authors` will be created in your default/current database, here the database `library` is to be used, but it hasn't been created. You should make a `library` database.

```
CREATE DATABASE library
```

Using a differently named database, or removing library from the create table statement may cause problems further down the tutorial.